# Windows struct initialization error C2099: initializer is not a constant

Tags: c, windows, dll, visual-studio-2017

I'm pretty new to Windows and I'm trying to compile a simple DLL on Windows with a global variable and use the global variable in my test application using Visual-Studio 2017 on Windows 10.

Here is the source code for the application

```
#include <stdio.h>

__declspec(dllimport) const char globalArr[];

typedef struct {
    const char *pData;
} MyStruct;

MyStruct myArr[] = {
    {
        globalArr
    }
};

int main() {
    printf("1 = %d\n", myArr[0].pData[0]);
    printf("2 = %d\n", myArr[0].pData[1]);
    printf("3 = %d\n", myArr[0].pData[2]);

    printf("1 = %d\n", globalArr[0]);
    printf("2 = %d\n", globalArr[1]);
    printf("3 = %d\n", globalArr[2]);

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the source code for the DLL

```
__declspec(dllexport) const char globalArr[] = {
    0x00, 0x01, 0x02
};
```

When I compile the main application using the following CMake project

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)

project(temp C)

add_library(mylib SHARED lib.c)
add_executable(myexec main.c)

target_link_libraries(myexec mylib)
```

I get the following error "main.c(11): error C2099: initializer is not a constant". Compiling this on linux seems to work (only difference is removing the __declspec). Why is Windows throwing a compile error?

Comment: Initializers must be known at compile-time and thus constant. Yet you are trying to use a value from a DLL loaded at run-time to initialize `myArr`. Initialize it in `main` using an assignment or whatever.

Answer (score 4):

With `__declspec(dllimport) const char globalArr[];` this means that the symbol `globalArr` will not get a value until the running executable is linked to the DLL.  Even when using an import library, this linking still happens at runtime.

"Load-time dynamic linking" is similar in procedure to "Run-time dynamic linking" except that it occurs before `main` is entered.

Therefore, the value cannot be used in a static data initializer because C requires those initializers to be known at compile-time.

Instead you can set the value in `main` after the DLL has been linked, e.g.:

```
MyStruct myArr[1];

int main()
{
    myArr[0].pData = globalArr;
}
```